# Button resize with image function works only when one button is created in the main window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

I created a function to resize an image on a button when this is resized (I wanted to keep a logo image in the upper left corner of the button and have the text in the middle of the button) which seems to work fine when a single button is created in the root window but when a second button is created the first button fills the whole root window and hides the second one.

Below is my code.

Could, please, anybody tell me what I doing wrong or how to solve my problem?

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageColor, ImageFont


root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_state("zoomed")

screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()
screenText = f'Screen Width: {screenWidth}\nScreen Height: {screenHeight}'


def OnEnter(event, color: str):
    event.widget['background'] = color

def OnLeave(event, color):
    event.widget['background'] = color


def OnButtonResize(event, logo: str, extraText: str = "") -> None:
    
    eventWidth = event.width
    eventHeight = event.height

    #print(f"Button resized to {eventWidth}x{eventHeight}")

    # create a larger transparent image (around the size of the button)
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (eventWidth, eventHeight), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    # paste the small image at the top-left corner of this large image
    img.paste(logo, (int(eventWidth/50), int(eventHeight/30)))
    
    #imgWidth, imgHeight = img.size
    buttonText = f"Button Width: {eventWidth}\nButton Height: {eventHeight}\n{extraText}"
    #print(buttonText)

    tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    
    event.widget['text'] = buttonText
    event.widget['image'] = tkimg
    event.widget.image = tkimg    # This line is to make the image persistent and avoid errors due to garbage collector


def Rgb2Hex(rgbTuple: tuple) -> str:
    
    return (f"#{rgbTuple[0]:02x}{rgbTuple[1]:02x}{rgbTuple[2]:02x}")


def Hex2Rgb(hexcode: str) -> tuple:
    
    return(ImageColor.getcolor(hexcode, "RGB"))


def MinMax(x: int) -> int:
    return(max(0, min(x, 255)))


def LightenHexColor(hexColorCode: str , percent: int = 10) -> str:
    
    inputColorTuple = Hex2Rgb(hexColorCode)
    
    ligtherColorTuple = ()
    for i in inputColorTuple:
        ligtherColorTuple = ligtherColorTuple + (MinMax(int(i*(100+percent)/100)),)

    return(Rgb2Hex(ligtherColorTuple))


def GetZoneNameImage(zoneName: str = "Z1", fontColor: str = "#000000") -> str:
    
    imageFilename = f"{zoneName}.png"
    font_size = 128
    font_filepath = "C:/Windows/Fonts/calibrii.ttf"
    
    color = Hex2Rgb(LightenHexColor(fontColor, -25))

    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_filepath, size=font_size)
    mask_image = font.getmask(zoneName, "L")
    img = Image.new("RGBA", mask_image.size)
    img.im.paste(color, (0, 0) + mask_image.size, mask_image)  # need to use the inner `img.im.paste` due to `getmask` returning a core
    img.save(imageFilename, quality=100)
    
    return(imageFilename)


helv32 = ("Helvetica", 32, "bold")

logoWidth = 150
logoHeight = 110

bgColorCursorOut1 = "#38bab6"
bgColorCursorIn1 = LightenHexColor(bgColorCursorOut1)

logoFilename1 = GetZoneNameImage(zoneName="Z1", fontColor=bgColorCursorOut1)

# load the required image and resize it to the desired size
logo1 = Image.open(logoFilename1).resize((logoWidth, logoHeight))
tkimg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo1)

bgColorCursorOut1 = "#38bab6"
bgColorCursorIn1 = LightenHexColor(bgColorCursorOut1)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text=screenText, image=tkimg1, compound="c", bg=bgColorCursorOut1, font=helv32)
button1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

button1.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: OnButtonResize(event, logo1, screenText))
button1.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: OnEnter(event, bgColorCursorIn1))
button1.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: OnLeave(event, bgColorCursorOut1))

bgColorCursorOut2 = "#FCBA03"
bgColorCursorIn2 = LightenHexColor(bgColorCursorOut2)

logoFilename2 = GetZoneNameImage(zoneName="Z2", fontColor=bgColorCursorOut2)

# load the required image and resize it to the desired size
logo2 = Image.open(logoFilename2).resize((logoWidth, logoHeight))
tkimg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo2)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text=screenText, image=tkimg2, compound="c", bg=bgColorCursorOut2, font=helv32)
button2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

button2.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: OnButtonResize(event, logo2))
button2.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: OnEnter(event, bgColorCursorIn2))
button2.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: OnLeave(event, bgColorCursorOut2))


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not resize the image to the same size of the button. The available space for the image is less than the size of the button because there are `padx` (1px), `borderwidth` (2px) and `highlightthickness` (1px) of the button that occupy space.  So the maximum size for the image should be `eventWidth-8` x `eventHeight-8`.

Comment: @acw1668 please either find an appropriate duplicate or write it up as an answer.

Comment: @acw1668, thanks. I have applied you suggestion and things are improving a great deal but now, when I resize the root window, the two buttons do not get resized with the same height and, eventually, the second button disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used `pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)` on the two buttons, then they will try to occupy the available space.  And you set the size of the image to the same size of the button and the available space inside the button is not large enough to hold the image (due to some space occupied by `padx`, `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` options). So `button1` will glow since it is the first button *packed* into the window, which triggers the `<Configure>` event again.

For your case, you can use `place()` instead of `pack()` to constraint the size of the buttons to half of the window:

```py
...
# button1 occupies the upper half of the window
button1.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.5)
...
# button2 occupies the low half of the window
button2.place(x=0, rely=0.5, relwidth=1, relheight=0.5)
```

You can use `grid()` with proper `.rowconfigure()` and `.columnconfigure()` to get the same result.

Comment: The solution you suggested using place throws an error:  _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage727" doesn't exist but using grid() all the problems seems to solved. Thanks.

Comment: @PaoloSestini I don't know how you implement my solution, but it works for me.

Comment: I just replaced the two lines:
...
button1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
...
button2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

with your suggested solution.

Comment: @PaoloSestini Try setting initial `width` and `height` options when creating the two buttons.

Comment: Yes, setting the initial width and height of the buttons solved the  _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage727" error. Thank you very much.